# Where does Windows 10 store background and lock screen pictures?

Tags: windows-10, desktop, desktop-customization, lock-screen

I am using one of the stock background pictures for my Windows Desktop background and would like to now make a slideshow as my background. I like the current stock picture that I have and would like to figure out where Windows puts them so I can copy the picture and add it to my slideshow.

Also, I have Windows Spotlight setting for my Lock Screen background. Where does Windows 10 store those pictures? (I want to use them for the same purpose). I know they are from the Internet, so maybe they are only available on Microsofts online server?

Comment: Duplicate https://superuser.com/q/1208076/

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure hidden folders are visible by opening an Explorer window and selecting Show Hidden items from the View tab.
2. Navigate to `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets`
3. Copy the files in this folder to another location on your computer where you can easily find them. Create a dedicated folder for these images.
4. In the Explorer window for the new folder, open a command prompt as an administrator from the File menu.
5. Run the following command to add a .jpg extension to all of the files you just copied: `ren *.* *.jpg`

What you’re left with will be a mixture of images, plus some assorted junk files that are used by the lock screen. You can delete any of the images that you don’t need. Again, be sure to only work out of a folder dedicated to the images you copied from the lock screen folder, as the renaming command could screw up other files if you’re not careful.

Source: [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-save-the-windows-10-lock-screen-images-you-like-1768783711)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Keeps telling me the following: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`    Any help??

Comment: That would be explorer.exe.  If the answer doesn't work it shouldn't be accepted

Comment: @WilliamV Does the error occur when you try to copy the files to a different folder or when you try to rename them?

Comment: It occurs in the command prompt when I try to run the command: `ren. .jpg`.

Comment: Are you running the command prompt from the newly created folder you copied the files to?

Comment: Yes. I am running command prompt from the folder I copied the files into as an administrator. I have no other programs open, NONE! Unless there are programs opened by Windows in the background that may be using the file.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro fixed the formatting of your answer for you.