# What's the source of those daily changing locked screen wallpapers on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

I have these automatically changing wallpapers active on my work laptop (not activated by me) and I think the vast majority is at least high quality, some are brilliant and a few I just adore.

What is the source of these images?

I'd definitely like to download or even buy some of them.

Comment: Are you referring to the pics in this folder: `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets` ? (they don't look like picture files but right-click any of the bigger files in that folder and choose "Open with" Windows Photo Viewer.

Comment: That's a lot of files ... I'll go through them during my lunchbreak. Could you formulate your response as an answer, in the meantime? Then I can accept it as a solution if it's what I need.

Comment: Are you referring to desktop wallpapers or lock screen backgrounds?

Comment: @SalmanA: The latter. They get automatically updated.

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-save-the-windows-10-lock-screen-images-you-like-1768783711 https://www.howtogeek.com/247643/how-to-save-windows-10s-lock-screen-spotlight-images-to-your-hard-drive/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The lock screen wallpapers can be found in the following directory:

```
C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets
```

When you navigate to that directory you will see a lot of files that don't look like picture files, as seen in the following screenshot:

[image: folder containing lock screen pics]

Right-click on any of the bigger files in that folder and select `Open with` and then select `Windows Photo Viewer` and you'll see that it is one of the Windows lock screen wallpapers.

[image]

Comment: Apparently it's only a subset, not the entire history, but that works!

Comment: Why do MS programmers not understand that such 'encrypted' files will be found inside file system in this very popular OS...  That's just a comment.

Comment: @Vyacheslav because they're not "encrypted", it was just convenient for MS developers to name cached images this way. I don't think they were trying to hide them.

Comment: This way they also won't show up in any searches you do as the indexer won't recognize them as images, thus not polluting your search results.

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively you can use [SpotBright](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/spotbright/9nblggh5km22) to download the images used for the lockscreen to a custom location. This has the added advantage that they are downloaded as image files *with* an extension.

You can also specify if you only want the landscape or also the portrait versions. This will allow you to also use them as a desktop background. Spotbright is a free Windows Store app.

Answer (score 4):

Source of the images depends on your choice in settings.

Lock Screen Setting:

[image]

- When you select "Windows Spotlight" in Settings > Personalization > Lock Screen, the images will be downloaded from Microsoft Server by backgroundTaskHost.exe and saved in "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets".
  You can view those images with changing extensions. Command:: `ren *.* *.jpg`
- When you select "Picture", the images will be choose from "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Theme1" folder which are preinstalled.
- Also lock screen images are saved temporarily in
  "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData"